# 'Expression is not a method' error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to pull up certain dialogResult boxes within a button click event that changes based on what radio button is selected, however when I create them both and try to attach them to the radio button checked selection, it says "Expression is not a method."

Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks

```
    Dim MsgBox1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You have chosen to   change your details to " + txtbox.Text + " percent"), "Are you sure?",   MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If MsgBox1 = DialogResult.Yes Then

    ElseIf MsgBox1 = DialogResult.No Then

    End If

    Dim MsgBox2 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You have chosen to cease this service", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If MsgBox2 = DialogResult.Yes Then

    ElseIf MsgBox2 = DialogResult.No Then

    End If

    If rdoEnable.Checked Then
        MsgBox1()
    End If

    If rdoCancel.Checked Then
        MsgBox2()
    End If
```

Comment: There are so many basic mistakes here, I'm not sure you understand ASP.NET or VB.NET

Comment: It would seem that you are working with a VB.NET WinForms application and not an ASP.NET application. Can we please get you clarify what you are trying to achieve. It appears that you have 2 radio buttons. When one is selected, you want a YesNo message box to appear with a certain message and when the other radio button is selected you want a YesNo message box to appear with a different message. Is that correct? And what do you want to happen if the user clicks on Yes as opposed to No?

Answer (score 1):

```
If rdoEnable.Checked Then
        MsgBox1()
    End If
```

It's occurring because `MsgBox1` is an instance of a `DialogResult` class, not a method. I don't know what you're trying to do, but that's not valid.

Also, you've tagged this as ASP.NET so I'll assume this is a web application. It appears you're using the `MessageBox` class from Windows Forms. You can't do that, you need to stick to controls available in a web context. Use [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) or some other tool for creating dialogs/popups on the client side.